# How to disable boot screen, just show the text output?

Tags: 12.10, boot, plymouth

When I turn on my computer, it shows a purple screen that says 'Ubuntu' in the middle. Pressing the 'down' key hides it and shows a terminal. How do I make it show the terminal by default? I've looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot) but it's for an older version (10.10) and none of it's answers worked. Uninstalling `plymouth-theme-*` packages just made the monitor stay off until the login screen loads, and editing `/etc/default/grub` wasn't possible because that file didn't exist.

Comment: I think your question could be [Missing /etc/default/grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257036/missing-etc-default-grub)!

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!